# How to automate Microfocus Rumba using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, automation, mainframe, microfocus

I'm trying to automate Microfocus Rumba application through VB.Net. Due to some constraints, I can't use any of the macros/scripts features that are inbuilt in Rumba.

I came to know that ehlapi32.dll can be used to automate Rumba but I couldn't add ehlapi32.dll or WHLLAPI.dll as references to the .Net solution.

I couldn't create objects of "Microfocus.Rumba"/"Rumba.System"/"Rumba.Application" because of the error "Cannot create Activex component". I tried to resolve it by registering the dll using RegAsm.exe. But it says the Dll is not a valid .net assembly.

I've attached the error snapshots.

[Error while adding the dlls in References section of the .Net solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWDJG.png)

[Cannot create ActiveX component error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvwvY.png)

[Not a valid .Net assembly error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsz0U.png)

Note : I'm using MicroFocus Rumba Desktop 9.4.1

Any guidance is deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WHLLAPI.DLL and EHLAPI32.dll are not an ActiveX com component (thus you can't register it with regsvr32, nor create a com interop to it by registering it with regasm), and it's not a .net assembly (thus you can't simply add a reference to it). It's just an 'old fashioned' call library.  You need to declare it, then you can make calls to it (via P/Invoke, to be technical).

Something like (the simplest version):

```
Declare Sub hllapi Lib "EHLAPI32.dll" (lpwFunction As Int32, ByVal lpbyString As String, lpwLength As Int32, lpwReturnCode As Int32)
```

Then call it

```
Dim status as Int32
Call hllapi(1, "A", 1, status)    ' Connect to Presentation Space A
```

You'll need to reference the HLLAPI documentation, multiple versions/instances of that documentation is available online, with examples (and it's mostly standard across vendors).  One is https://docs.attachmate.com/extra/x-treme/apis/ehllapi.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much MarkL. I will try it out and update.

Comment: Hi MarkL, I tried it in the way you said. The same code you gave works when written as Excel macro but it is not working in VB.Net. Am I missing something?

Comment: I included  "Connect to PS" function and "Send Key" function in VB.Net. I'm getting a return code of 2 for both functions. What is strange is that, there is no explanation for Return code of 2 for "Connect to PS" in the EHLLAPI guide.

Comment: Return status values are uniform across all the HLLAPI functions.  2 is invalid argument.  That it isn't documented as a return status for the Attachmate HLLAPI but you're receiving it when calling Rumba HLLAPI says that you need the Rumba HLLAPI documentation.  I don't know where to locate that (I didn't go looking).  I did say that HLLAPI is mostly standard across vendors, this is likely a difference between Attachmate and Rumba - one can return a 2 for ConnectPS while the other doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your response MarkL. The same code you gave works when written as Excel macro but it is not working in VB.Net. Am I missing something? I'm wondering how the code worked in Excel macro but not working in VB.Net. So I think this is something apart from the HLLAPI documentation.